# PDF Arranger trying to export pages to make a new PDF of just the first few pages

Tags: pdf

I try to export selection to a new single file and it gives me the error message
"Use pikepdf.Pdf.pages interface to copy pages from one PDF to another"

trying to use the alternative pdfsam gives me this output

```
$ pdfsam Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
```

Answer (score 1):

Export all the pages that you want to reuse as individual single-page PDFs, then import these individual pages back into a new PDF Arranger window and save them all together as a new multi-page PDF document.

1. Click the first page that you want to export, then use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and the left mouse button to select the other pages that you want to export one by one until you have selected all of the pages that you want to export.
2. Click the three horizontal lines Main Menu icon <kbd>≡</kbd> in PDF Arranger and select *Export* -> *Export Selection to Individual Files*. If you have selected five pages then this will export each of these pages to an individual PDF file.
3. Import the single page PDFs that you saved into a new PDF Arranger window. Click the three horizontal lines Main Menu icon <kbd>≡</kbd> and select the *Save as* option to save all the pages that you imported into PDF Arranger as a new multi-page PDF document.

---

The PDF Split and Merge application (*pdfsam*) from the default Ubuntu repositories can also be used to extract a selection of pages as a new PDF document. pdfsam can be installed by `sudo apt install pdfsam` in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. The **Extract** tool can be used to specify a list of pages separated by a commas used as delimiter characters, and the whole list of pages can be saved as a new PDF document by clicking the  <kbd>▶  Run</kbd>  button in the lower left corner as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I tried export selection to individual files it gives me the same error message

Comment: @ubuntunoob The PDF Split and Merge application (*pdfsam*) from the default Ubuntu repositories can also be used to extract a selection of pages as a new PDF document. I edited my answer and added the instructions for using it.

Comment: `$ pdfsam
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
 at`

Comment: @ubuntunoob Your Ubuntu definitely has a software issue. All of the relevant information about this software issue should be copied to your question, so that all Ask Ubuntu users can read it.

Comment: which info would that be?

Comment: The third comment below this answer.